# Struggling to Get Data With JSOUP

Tags: jsoup

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. I am attempting to use JSOUP to get some data.

This is the line of HTML that I am trying to parse:

```
<div class=\"esg-media-video\" data-youtube=\"DeL2uzgOW8U\" width=\"640\" height=\"480\" data-poster=\"\"></div>
```

I am trying to get the string from data-youtube: DeL2uzgOW8U

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);

Element youTube = doc.select("div.esg-media-video").first();
```

But, it is not working. The document has the correct code in it, but the Element is always empty. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: what is android tag to do with this ?

Comment: Sorry, I am using this in my Android app, but I guess it is not exclusive to Android.

Comment: In your example the div IS empty. So what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to extract the value of `data-youtube` attribute, you can try the following code:

```
        String html = "<div class=\"esg-media-video\" data-youtube=\"DeL2uzgOW8U\" width=\"640\" height=\"480\" data-poster=\"\"></div>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        Element el = doc.select("div").first();
        String dataYoutubeGrabber = el.attr("data-youtube");
        System.out.println(dataYoutubeGrabber);
```

**The output will be:** DeL2uzgOW8U